# What does きかい and おより mean on this question?

Tags: words, jlpt

[image]

The correct answer is 1 but I do not understand it completely,based on what I know, the meaning is "When there's the existing machine,please get near to it"
which does not make a lot of sense. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I think next time you should try looking words up in the dictionary. There was no need for this question.

Comment: Totally off-topic but I guess you're using a textbook from good old days or printed outside Japan. That nostalgic typeface's nearly died out along with phototypesetters in Japan.

Answer (score 7):

The correct answer is indeed 「きかい」 but this is not the 「きかい」 you are thinking of.

> 「機会{きかい}」 = "a chance" or "an opportunity"
>
> 「機械{きかい}」 = "a machine"

The correct answer, of course, is the former.

> "If you have a chance to come to my area, by all means, please drop by."

「お寄{よ}り」 is the honorific noun  form of the verb 「寄{よ}る」, which means "to drop by".